# Inconsistent behavior for Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to update the data in Firebase Realtime Database through Android app. It will  only occasionally work after I open the app and wait for some time. Most of the time it does not work. In my case, working mean the data is updated in cloud. I am wondering why it work sometimes and do not work sometimes. There is no error or warning in Logcat. Once it works, it will continue to work until the app is restarted.

**DbHelper class**

```
public class DbHelper {
    static final String TAG = "ttt";

    int count = 0;

    private static FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private static DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

    TextView tv;

    public DbHelper(final TextView tv){
        this.tv = tv;

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                tv.setText(text);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    public void testing(){
        myRef.setValue("test"+count++);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textTesting;
    DbHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        textTesting = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_testing);
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(textTesting);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dbHelper.testing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Added**

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (connected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "not connected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
    }
});
```

**Logcat**

> 11-14 20:26:58.956 19329-19384/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>
> 11-14 20:26:58.956 19329-19384/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
>
> 11-14 20:26:58.961 19329-19384/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 167270724
>
> 11-14 20:26:58.986 19329-19384/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
>
> 11-14 20:26:59.001 19329-19329/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@34fb88b7 time:15941479
>
> 11-14 20:26:59.006 19329-19384/? V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
>
> 11-14 20:26:59.056 19329-19336/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
>
> 11-14 20:26:59.541 19329-19329/? D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>
> 11-14 20:26:59.631 19329-19329/? D/ttt: Value is: test0
>
> 11-14 20:27:02.366 19329-19329/? D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
>
> 11-14 20:27:02.451 19329-19329/? D/ttt: Value is: test1
>
> 11-14 20:27:04.166 19329-19384/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>
> 11-14 20:28:07.721 19329-19329/? D/FA: Service connection suspended

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? What happens? Do you see any errors or messages in Logcat?

Comment: Is there any reason why you put Firebase operations in a separate class instead of using instant creations?

Comment: @Grimthorr The data is updated locally but not updated in cloud. There is no error or even warning for that

Comment: @CoolGuyCG I just try to make it tidy. Is it the reason behind?

Comment: @SamTew Do you have [disk persistence ("*offline capabilities*")](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) enabled? If the data is updated locally but never synced to Firebase: it sounds like a network issue.

Comment: @Grimthorr No, I din enable it. Yup, it looks like network issue but my phone can surf internet. Any other reason?

Comment: @SamTew Check Logcat for any messages from Firebase such as `D/FA: Connected to remote service` to see if your app is actually connecting to the Firebase services.

Comment: @Grimthorr I have added the logcat. Can you help me to take a look?

Comment: @Grimthorr I added the code to check the connection as updated in the question. It shows not connected. Any idea? I have added the internet permission in manifest.

Comment: @SamTew You do get the `D/FA: Connected to remote service` log though so it does seem to be connecting to Firebase. Does your new connection state listener log "not connected" then? I'm not sure why it would only work intermittently, that's strange.

Comment: @Grimthorr Yes, it shows not connected.

Comment: @Grimthorr I found out the reason. The DNS used by ISP is the problem. Change to Google DNS solved my problem

Comment: @SamTew Glad you got it sorted. Feel free to add an answer to your own question as it may help other readers.